# How to disable my laptop's defective keyboard?

Tags: keyboard, device-manager

I have an Alienware M17x R2, and after a couple years of use I started having problems with the keyboard: Intermittently, and without warning or apparent cause (even if I'm not touching the computer), the S key (and more recently the D key) will start firing incessant signals until I hit the offending key.

I've been using a USB keyboard, which is conveniently exactly the right size to fit over the built-in keyboard without touching any buttons. However, even as I type the defective keyboard will fire its stream of signals.

I have contacted Dell about this, twice in fact. The first time, I was just bluntly told that they don't ship replacement keyboards. The second time I was told that they did, but they were out of stock and they would contact me when they were in stock again. They haven't contacted me since.

I can't seem to work out which device to disable in the device manager. Here's a screenshot of what I have:

[image]

None of the keyboard devices have "Disable" in their context menus, only "Uninstall"... so you'll understand if I'm hesitant to try anything myself.

Any advice on how to fix this?

Comment: The `Standard PS/2 Keyboard` is your internal keyboard, while the other 4 are devices from your USB keyboard that you've plugged in.

Comment: Out of curiosity, what did you end up doing to fix it?

Comment: Actually, I haven't fixed it. But since yours was the best answer and I'm too lazy to actually disconnect it, I accepted it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A more drastic, but effective approach would be to remove the keyboard itself, disconnect it from the mainboard (the little gold ribbon) and reattach the keyboard.

Keys wont work if they're not plugged in...

PS. if you contact dell, many times they can send you a replacement keyboard (they are usually covered under warranty, but even if they aren't, they can still sell you one.) I know you've had bad experience, but keep barking up the phone tree till you get the US call center. They will help you (even if it's just to get you to shut up)

Also, http://www.keyboard-store.com/dell-alienware-m17xr2-laptop-keyboard.html

Answer (score 2):

I would first look into the BIOS to see if there's an option in there somewhere to disable the keyboard (or maybe the PS/2 inputs). This could, of course, render your laptop inoperative if you don't have a USB keyboard with it at all times.

Worst-case, you can always try uninstalling the `Standard PS/2 Keyboard` (your internal keyboard) and see if you can keep windows from trying to reinstall the drivers for it.