# Constant beeping

Tags: windows-8, laptop, usb, keyboard, water-damage

My computer has a problem with beeping. I'll first tell you how it started:

One night I decided to watch a cartoon, and I took some water and food with me to eat while I watch. I fell asleep and when I woke up I had spilled water all over my keyboard. I didn't react quickly, because it went unnoticed for about 1 and a half hours. When I noticed, I quickly put my laptop on a radiator to try to dry it.

When I turned the computer on there was a constant beeping sound. I didn't know what caused it, and I'm still not sure, but I think it has something to do with the USB hub. If I let the computer stand for some hours without any USB connections, it's fine, but when I put any kind of USB device in, it starts beeping. The laptop keyboard doesn't work so I have to have some kind of USB device connected to use the computer.

The beeping is going on while I'm writing this and it makes my computer lag so much that it can make delays from the keyboard be from 1 second to 10 seconds. I need this computer because I don't have the money to buy a new one, and I have to use this computer for homework and games. The beeping is constant, with less than a second between beeps.

If anyone has a solution, please help.

Comment: Which operating system are you using?

Comment: Look through [the water-damage tag](http://superuser.com/questions/tagged/water-damage), which should have some pointers.

Comment: You might want to [try this](http://superuser.com/a/486417/167187) and see if you have a BIOS setting that lets you disable the keyboard.

Comment: I'm using Windows 8.

Comment: I have tried to disable the keyboard once before, but it just says uninstall, so I clicked uninstall and i restarted the computer, and the laptop keyboard driver thing was still there.

Comment: When you say you hear constant beeping sound, do you mean [this sound](http://www.eightforums.com/sound-audio/22273-annoying-usb-connect-disconnect-sound.html)?

Comment: @BogiJuulPeterson Yeah, I'm sorry about the disable keyboard comment. I realized you can't uninstall the device after I posted the comment

Comment: yeah, and it has a little click sound after every beep.

Comment: Additionally, you might also want to [try this](https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/forum/windows_7-hardware/why-is-the-usb-disconnection-sound-repeating-over/b5a46408-8f58-e011-8dfc-68b599b31bf5)

Comment: If this information would help, I often get the beeping sound to stop when i take out every USB connection and turn off the computer and take out the battery then hold the turn off/on button for a minute and then turn on the computer and then the beeping will stop for a few minutes.

Comment: What is the make and model of your laptop? Sounds like you short circuited at least the keyboard and maybe other components. First thing I'd try is to unplug the laptop keyboard from the motherboard. Depending on your make and model, it could be a simple job with some precision tools. If unplugging the keyboard from the motherboard works, then you can continue using an external keyboard. When you have more money, you can replace the laptop keyboard with a new one from eBay. I spilled coffee on mine and it cost me $45 to replace the broken laptop keyboard.

Comment: Thanks Sun W Kim, since you helped me fix my Toshiba c850! I disconnected my Laptop keyboard from the mother board and the constant beeping stopped. I thank all of you guys for helping me out!

Answer (score 0):

Plug in a USB keyboard. Go to device manager and delete the laptop keyboard (not the USB one you just added). Does the beeping stop? If so then replace the keyboard. Fairly easy (usually) and probably less than $40.

Or just disconnect the keyboard cable (underneath the keyboard) and use only the USB keyboard.